# Mail from VFS to collect passport

Tags: visas, uk

I applied at new york premium center on friday with gold service. Monday morning I got mail that decision has been made. but I have not yet received any instructions from VFS to collect my passport. I had told them I will collect passport in person. How long does VFS takes to send email to collect passport. I am super worried. Thanks. the reason for taking gold service was to make it faster. I plan to travel in first week of may

Answer (score 1):

it took two days. Monday morning mail from UK gov. And tuesday 6 pm mail from VFS. That is time line. Thursday collected passport with visa.